# after downloading ubuntu can I revert back to Windows 8?

Tags: installation

I am thinking of trying out Ubuntu and if I don't care for it, can I easily revert back to windows 8 or can it be run side by side with windows 8?

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is to choose Try Ubuntu, before you do any thing else.

[image]

Once you try it, and you decide that you like it,  you can install it along side windows,

[image]

and yes if you decide that you don't want it, you can [revert back to windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).